# Sending a large message from child iframe to parent in IE7

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-7, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, postmessage

I am using parent.postmessage for IE8+.

The only alternative I am seeing for IE7 is to use the hash hack, e.g. "example.com/index.html#{the-message-here}", but my message can be thousands of characters long, and this method is constrained by the 2,083 character limit.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you cited is your only option in IE7 or older, since the Web Messaging API was only first supported in IE8.